# elasticsearch giving more weight to different fields and scenarios

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elastic4s

I have this ES query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "test",
            "fields": [
              "name^-1.0",
              "id^-1.0",
              "address.city^-1.0",
              "address.street^-1.0"
            ],
            "type": "phrase_prefix",
            "lenient": "true"
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost": 1.0,
      "minimum_should_match": "1"
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}
```

and currently what happens is, when I search for person with the name `john`, I will get bunch of results that the `id, address.city, address.street` contains john in them, which is fine, but I want `name` to be more important, and also if I have in the es 2 people `john` and someone with 2 names like `george john` I would want the just `john` to come up first.

can I do that? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make any field more important than other(s), you can set its boost to a higher value. So if `fieldA^4` and `fieldB^1` it implies that `fieldA` is 4 times more important than `fieldB`. Therefore you can give higher boost value to `name` field to make it more important for scoring.

For second point the document with `name` field value as `john` will have higher score than with a document having `name` field value as `george john` *(assuming that other fields have same data in both documents)*. The reason you are get the second doc *(george john)* higher in result is because you have boosted all the fields with negative value.

So to cater to both of your points

- give higher boost to `name`
- make boost for all fields as positive value.

So the query should look as below:

```
{
  //"explain": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "john",
            "fields": [
              "name^4.0",
              "id^1.0",
              "address.city^1.0",
              "address.street^1.0"
            ],
            "type": "phrase_prefix",
            "lenient": "true"
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost": 1,
      "minimum_should_match": "1"
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}
```

To understand more on how the score for the matching document is calculated by elastic, you can use the `"explain": true` in your query. This will give detailed steps in result, taken by elastic to calculate the score.

Comment: Nice explanation. How it would look like if each field have different query? ex. name: john address: some address

Comment: @VladimirDjukic In that case there would be two queries inside should/must clause as per the requirement. In each query target fields could be different or even same and that too depends. But you might have different boost levels for fields in each of these query based on the preference.